# Converting varchar to int

Tags: sql, type-conversion

I have the following code;
I'm trying to convert varchar to int and I get an error.

Essentially I want to get the following result:

```
@OutletID = 423,324
```

Can anyone help?

```
Declare @outlet varchar(1000),
    @outletID int


Select @outlet = '423,324'


Select '@Outlet',@outlet


Select @OutletID = Convert(int, @outlet, @OutletID)
```

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '423,324' to data type int

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma's (I assume they're the thousand-separator) before the conversion:

```
select @OutletID = cast(replace(@outlet, ',', '') as int)
```

Comment: No they are not thousand-separator, it's two different numbers/IDs

Comment: Ok, how do you expect SQL Server to store two different numbers in one integer ?

Comment: Is there another way though??

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function to remove all the commas before converting. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9315)

```
declare @outlet varchar(1000)= '3,324,345', @outletId int

select @outletId = convert(int,replace(@outlet,',',''))
select @outletId
```

Or if you are trying to get them separated into two variables (as per comment above) then; [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9321)

```
declare @outlet varchar(1000)= '123,345', @id1 int, @id2 int

select @id1=left(@outlet,charindex(',',@outlet,1)-1),
       @id2=right(@outlet,len(@outlet)-charindex(',',@outlet,1))

select @id1,@id2
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you can use `REPLACE` as part of your cast:

```
select cast(replace(replace(@v3, char(13), ''), char(10), '') as int)
```

If this is something that will be happening often, it would be better to clean up the data and modify the way the table is populated to remove the CR and LF before it is entered.

Or go to this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx